# Stuck on integrating $\int \frac{e^x}{e^{2x}-1}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I hope it's okay, but I wanted to show where I got stuck.

**Problem**: $$\int \frac{e^x}{e^{2x} -1} \ dx.$$

**Attempt**:

Let $u=e^{x}-1,$ and $u+1=e^x$ and $\ du= e^x \ dx.$

Then we get

$$\int \frac{u+1}{(u+1)^2-1} \ du.$$

Is there a possible trigonometric substitution of the form $$\int \frac{a}{x^2+a^2} \ dx$$ ?

Not sure.. have

$$\int \frac{e^x}{e^x \left(e^x-e^{-x} \right)} \ dx$$

Comment: Photos are highly unwelcomed on the site.

Comment: The answer has already said which substitution to use, but I thought I'd give this link anyway: [LINK](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+e%5Ex%2F%7Be%5E%7B2x%7D-1%7D). When doing such integration questions, Wolfram Alpha is really useful to get a hint from - type in your integral and click on "step-by-step solution", and it will show a possibly helpful next step. Here it says the substitution $u=e^x$.

Answer (score 5):

Try letting $u=e^x.$ Then use partial fractions.

Comment: Thank you, sorry I don't understand. how is setting $u = e^{x}$ going to give me the ability to use partial fractions? I don't see it. I realize it's a fraction which is an indication of partial fractions but other than that I am not connecting the dots.

Comment: @yre you get $$\int \frac{\mathrm{d}u}{u^2 - 1} = \int \frac{\mathrm{d}u}{(u-1)(u+1)}$$ which is amenable to partial fractions, since you can split it up into two things of the form $1/1+x$ or $1/1-x$ to get an easy logarithm.

Comment: @ZainPatel thank you, wasn't making that connection. That was like wrapped in a riddle, didn't really appear like partial fractions until some algebra revealed its true colors.

Comment: @ZainPatel wouldn't there still be a 'u' in the numerator?

Comment: @yre no, that's what the $\mathrm{d}u$ is for (see my answer as well). You have $$\int \frac{e^x}{e^{2x} - 1} \, \mathrm{d}x = \int \frac{u}{u^2 - 1} \cdot \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}u} \, \mathrm{d}u  = \int \frac{\color{red}{u}}{u^2 - 1} \cdot \frac{1}{\color{red}{u}} \, \mathrm{d}u$$

Comment: @Zain Patel thank you I can see it clearly now.

Comment: @Zain Patel I just tried this, I was confused by the rules, why do the e^x's cancel before the u sub is made? Or does hat not matter because they are equivalent?

Comment: @yre it doesn't matter, they are equivalent. You can cancel them out before as well.

Comment: @Zain Patel was there any way to tell this was going to be a partial fractions problem?

Comment: $e^{2x}$ is a square. You know how to integrate $u/(u^2-1)$ and even $1/(u^2-1)$. The key in integration is to keep in mind what you know how to integrate, and what steps you can take to make what you have look like something you can integrate. This takes experience, doing lots of problems, and asking some questions. I used to tell my students that integration is an art. You have to store up by experience what works and what does not for certain kinds of integrals. You have to remember what you did and store it away for future reference.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, continuing from where you've left off: Note that $(u+1)^2 - 1 =u(u+2)$ via difference of squares and then apply partial fractions to $\frac{1}{u(u+2)}$. This isn't as efficient as Chris's answer but continues directly from your progress.

Note also that in your answer, you've forgotten to take into account the $\mathrm{d}u$ factor.

Answer (score 2):

$$
 I = \int \frac{e^{x}}{\color{blue}{e^{2x} - 1}} dx =
\int \frac{e^{x}}{\left( \color{blue}{e^{x} + 1} \right)\color{blue}{\left( e^{x} - 1 \right)}} dx
$$

Let $\color{red}{u=e^{x}+1}$, then
$$
 u=e^{x}+1, \quad du = e^{x} dx, \quad e^{x} - 1 = u - 2
$$

$$
  I 
= \int \frac{du}{u(u-2)} 
= \frac{1}{2}\int \left( \frac{1}{u-2}-\frac{1}{u} \right) du
= \frac{1}{2} \ln \left( \frac{2-u}{u} \right)
$$

Substitute back
$$
\int \frac{e^{x}}{e^{2x} - 1} dx 
= \frac{1}{2} \ln \left( \frac{1-e^{x}}{1+e^{x}} \right) 
$$

Comment: By the recommendations i did partial fractions with u = e^x and got : -lnle^xl +lnle^x -1l + C.  What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 0):

for a bit of variety make the substitution $x=2iz$ so the integral becomes:
$$
\int \frac{e^{2iz}}{e^{4iz}-1}2idz = \int\frac{dz}{\sin 2z}=\frac12\int\frac{\sec^2 z}{\tan z}dz=\frac12 \log \tan z + C
$$
since 
$$
\tan z = -i\frac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{e^{iz}+e^{-iz}} = -i \frac{e^x-1}{e^x+1}
$$
we have 
$$
I = \frac12\log \tan z + C = \frac12 \log \frac{e^x-1}{e^x+1} +C'
$$
where $C'=C-\frac{i\pi}2$.